# Can't add Facebook API data to Database - won't $.post name, email

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook, facebook-apps

I've been struggling with this for hours...

I have a Login with Facebook button on my site and I'm trying to add the authenticated user data to a database. Hoping maybe a fresh pair of eyes can find my mistake, so here's what I have.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId   : 'MY APP ID',
        oauth   : true,
        status  : true, // check login status
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
    });

  };

function fb_login(){
    FB.login(function(response) {

        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            //console.log(response); // dump complete info
            access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
            user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                 $.post("addtodb.php", {name: response.name})
            });

            window.location.href = "next.php"; //redirect once authorized

            FB.api('/me/devlogintest:join', 'action', 
            { object : 'http://www.mysite.com' });

        } else {
            //user hit cancel button
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');

        }
    }, {
        scope: 'email,publish_actions'
    }
    );
}
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

The addtodb.php script...

```
<?php

include('config.php');
$fbname = $_POST['name'];

if(!empty($_POST)){ //won't submit blanks if no data

// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect($Host,$Username,$Password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($Database) or die(mysql_error());

// Insert rows
mysql_query("INSERT INTO fbusers 
(name) VALUES('$fbname') ") 
or die(mysql_error());  
}
?>
```

I can't seem to get the user's name to Post and add to the database. If I use an alert on the javascript, it does popup the correct information. There also doesn't seem to be any errors on the php script side when I enable error checking.

Jquery call is included in head tags.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it just me, or are you calling `$results = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());` before you first define `$query`?

Comment: Nope, it's not just you. OP's code is also wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Whoops... I forgot to paste that in. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

One of major issues in your code is usage of redirection just after running async code... `FB.api` and `$.post` working in asynchronous manner so redirection to `next.php` may occur before `FB.api` returned data and/or `$.post` submitted data to server.

As said in comments `$results = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());` will rise warning of `$query` not being defined and result in empty query. If the script was called (it's probably not) you should see that warning in logs (with error reporting enabled).

Try to move the redirection code within callback function of `$.post` so it'll wait until your scripts received data.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the issue. When I comment out the redirect, it works perfectly. I tried to move the redirect code to other parts of the script, but can't figure out where to place it (not entirely sure what you mean "within the callback function," being the novice that I am. Any suggestions?

Comment: Got it - thanks. I'm learning!
Moved redirect and added function like this... 

`$.post("addtodb.php", {name: response.name}, function() { window.location.href = "next"; })`